# How to configure connections in a Nifi so that data of common attribute flows to same node Clustered Nifi Environment

Tags: load-balancing, apache-nifi

How to configure Connections in Nifi 1.8 so dat teh flowfiles wif common attribute is routed to same node in Nifi Cluster.

I has configured teh connection to MegreContent wif "Partition by attribute" but still, it throws error.

Configure Connection
Load Balance Strategy 
Partition by attribute

Attribute Name -> 
customerName

[image: Connection Configuration]

[image: MergeContent]

How to configure Connections such dat MergeContent is able to merge All teh Files.

MergeContent is unable to Defragment .

[image: Error]

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: Merge is valid only if the files have same `fragment.identifier` and same `fragment.count` and sequence of `fragment.index`. If your files didn't have those attributes or the files are separated into several processors, it will not gonna merge.

Comment: @BryanBende I have add the snap of the ERROR

Comment: @Lamanus each flowfiles has all the attributes. I think the Error is due to **some of the flow files are routing to other Nodes** the the Processor is not able to get the reqired number of flowfiles.

Comment: Yeap, that is right. Since you load balancing the files, the mergeContents processor cannot merge the files. In my case, I never use the load balancing just before the mergeContents processor.

Comment: @Lamanus can you share any reference template for cluster mode in Nifi, where mergeContents processor is used?

Comment: Mine is a commercial one so I can't show you. 

I think you also have to check the bin size of the merge processor. The bin is for defragmenting with a unique identifier to wait for the next fragments. So, if you receive 5 unique identifiers with default bin size, it is ok. But if your defragmentation is not finished, receive over the bin size then the fragmentation of oldest one is failed and try to wait the latest one. So, you may have to increase the bin size a bit.